# CSS Heightspace Invisible Character

Tags: css, whitespace

Is there a way to CSS an invisible characters so I can add it and adjust the height space?

For example:
At the moment I'm using `&nbsp;` and `&thinsp;` but I want to specify the height of a blank white space using px.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can wrap the invisible char in an inline element and then specify the line height property to that element:

HTML:

```
<span class="invisible-element">&nbsp;</span>
```

CSS:

```
span.invisible-element {
  line-height: 12px;
}
```